# Nodejistu deploy error

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal, nodejitsu

I have a Nodejitsu app that I've been able to successfully deploy a bunch of times previously. My last deploy was about 2 weeks ago.

I went to deploy yesterday and again today and got an error that isn't really giving me enough information to find and resolve the issue.

The console output (after the output for the npm installation) is as follows:

```
info:    Updating app split-app
info:    Activating snapshot 0.1.1-26 for split-app
info:    Starting app split-app
error:   Error running command deploy
error:   Errors occured while starting the application
error:   Error starting application. This could be a user error.
error:   info: Running start for app.
error:   info: Cleaning /opt/run
error:   info: Fetching application snapshot...
error:   info: Application snapshot fetched.
error:   info: Unpacking snapshot...
error:   info: Reading `package.json`...
error:   info: Starting application...
error:   info: Spawn: start --min-uptime 2000 -o /opt/run/forza.log -- forza -h multiplex.nodejitsu.com -p 8556 --start-log /opt/run/start.log --app-user alexcoady --app-name split-app -- node webapp/server.js
error:   info: `aeternum` pid: 31722
error:   info: Writing pidfile: /root/app.pid
error:   info: Tailing forza log: /opt/run/start.log
error:   info: Tail closing..
error:   info: Retry # 1 with 1000ms interval
error:   info: Tailing forza log: /opt/run/start.log
error:   info: Tail closing..
error:   info: Retry # 2 with 6655ms interval
error:   info: Tailing forza log: /opt/run/start.log
error:   
error:   timers.js:103
error:               if (!process.listeners('uncaughtException').length) throw e;
error:                                                                         ^
error:   Error: spawn ENOMEM
error:       at errnoException (child_process.js:855:11)
error:       at ChildProcess.spawn (child_process.js:802:11)
error:       at exports.spawn (child_process.js:626:9)
error:       at tailLog (/opt/local/lib/node_modules/solenoid/lib/solenoid.js:502:18)
error:       at /opt/local/lib/node_modules/solenoid/lib/solenoid.js:497:15
error:       at reconnect.delay (/opt/local/lib/node_modules/solenoid/node_modules/back/index.js:42:5)
error:       at Timer.list.ontimeout (timers.js:101:19)
```

Might anyone be able to offer some insight? Just ask if I can provide anything else of use.